# Use Loopback + Portable Runner with docker-compose on Mac

Tags: docker-compose, apache-beam

I am trying to setup a local Beam Runner for easier testing/developing.
I'd like to allow testing python pipeline which uses kafka IO locally on my mac.
Here's my current plan for the entire framework looks like:

[image]

Here's my current `docker-compose`

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
  jobmanager:
    image: flink_image
    command: ['jobmanager']
    environment:
      FLINK_PROPERTIES: "jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager\nparallelism.default: 2"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
  taskmanager:
    image: flink_image
    scale: 1
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: ['taskmanager']
    environment:
      FLINK_PROPERTIES: "jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager\ntaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2\nparallelism.default: 2"
  beam-jobserver:
    image: flink_image
    ports:
      - "8097:8097"
      - "8098:8098"
      - "8099:8099"
    entrypoint:
      - java
      - -cp
      - /target/flink/flink-web-upload/beam-runner.jar
      - org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkJobServerDriver
      - --flink-master=jobmanager
      - --job-host=0.0.0.0
```

And my pipeline looks like this:

```
LOCAL_ARGS = [
    '--streaming',
    '--runner=portableRunner',
    '--environment_type=LOOPBACK',
    '--job_endpoint=localhost:8099',
    '--artifact_endpoint=localhost:8098',
    '--defaultEnvironmentType=EXTERNAL',
    '--defaultEnvironmentConfig=host.docker.internal:5000',
]

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(LOCAL_ARGS)) as pipeline:
    result = (
        pipeline 
        | "Kafka Read" >> ReadFromKafka(
            consumer_config={"bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'},
            topics=["test.topic"],
            with_metadata=False,
            expansion_service=default_io_expansion_service(
                append_args=[
                    '--defaultEnvironmentType=PROCESS',
                    "--defaultEnvironmentConfig={\"command\":\"/opt/apache/beam/java_boot\"}",
                    '--experiments=use_deprecated_read',
                ]
                )
        )
       | "logging" >> beam.Map(lambda x: logging.info(f"logged: {x}"))
    )
```

However, it looks like the `LOOPBACK` tried to open a port on my host machine, and ask the task manager to talk to itself via `localhost:<randomPort>`.  Which is not accessible inside the container.

Unfortunately, `host` network is not supported for Docker on Mac, and thus I need to find a way to overwrite the Loopback settings so that it connect to `host.docker.internal:<dedicated_pool>` instead of a random port on my host machine? or if there are other suggested workaround?  Thanks!

(The entire infra can be found here: https://gist.github.com/lydian/0db7614652c2ccdc733884134bf67f9b)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not supported. LOOPBACK mode is mostly targeting very simple setups.

You could come close by starting the worker manually, e.g.

`python -m apache_beam.runners.worker.worker_pool_main --service_port =PORT`

and then passing `--environment_type=EXTERNAL --environment_config= host.docker.internal:PORT`.

Answer (score 0):

I was just facing similar struggles recently. Luckily there's two environment variables that facilitate testing on Docker for Mac. Unfortunately, there's not much documentation around that currently.

- `DOCKER_MAC_CONTAINER=1` limits the ports for communication with SDK workers to the range 8100 - 8200 instead of using random ports. Ports of that range are used in a round-robin fashion and have to be published.
- `BEAM_WORKER_POOL_IN_DOCKER_VM=1` tells an SDK worker to communicate with a runner node using `host.docker.internal` / via the docker host instead of using `localhost`.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/mosche/beam-portable-spark/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L40-L51) how to use these with Spark, but Flink shouldn't be any different